# how to point out dynamic text file with time stamp to schedule in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package

Every day i am generating text file with time stamp and insert into table.so i am not able to point out Second day file in flat file source connection Manager that file should be dynamic data.I am doing automate the scheduled SSIS package in SQL .So,How can we point pout second day file .please any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for each loop container to pick files dynamically from a specific folder.

Pass the configuration in **For each loop Editor** :

**Folder :**  Path of the folder to pick the files. It can be a variable also,to make it configurable.

**Files :**  Type of the files (eg: .csv)

**Retrieve File Name :** Name, Path etc. whichever you need

See the screenshot [image: For Each Loop Editor]

Let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: but the thing is file generate with time stamp only.how can i point out that

Comment: here file name with time stamp that  time_stamp only dynamic.so is it possible to do in for each loop?ex:file1_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.txt.

Comment: Yes, For each loop will pick each file even with different timestamps from the folder you will specify in the 'Directory' expression

Comment: can you please give example or screen shot.Thanks in advance

Comment: i am not able to see that directory option in that collection tab

Comment: You have to click on Collection then expand Expressions. Here you will see directory. Select the variable containing directory path. Now, you have to define the type of file you want to pick.

Comment: In directory what i have to give like when i add  variable for file path that variable expression i need to give?

Comment: Yes, refer the screenshot i provided in my answer

Comment: Hope this helped you